# Connect to PostGIS database from QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql

I am having trouble connecting to a PostgreSQL database hosed on my local host.  I have a Python script to connect and connected through the command line, but for the life of me can't connect to a the database from QGIS.  Here is the Python code I got to work:

```
import psycopg2    
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mb_sed_class' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='Daniel'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

print ("I connected to the database")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
print cur.fetchall()
```

This connected to the database and returned the names tables.  And here is how I connected to it from the command line:

```
psql -d mb_sed_clsss -U postgres
```

The command line prompted me to input my password and it opened the psql interpreter.

A screen shot of my Create a New PostGIS Connection dialog can be found [here](https://etal.egnyte.com/dl/nWskKDCsHY).  When I try an connect with those inputs I get the error:

```
FATAL: pssword Authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

I am running QGIS 2.8.2 and PostgreSQL 9.4 on windows 8 64 bit machine.

Comment: Your script doesn't really test connection works. Try doing a simple select query. cur = conn.cursor()...cur.execute("SELECT * FROM yourtable;")...cur.fetchone() and do a print out.

Comment: Are you sure about the exterior inverted commas: `conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mb_sed_class' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='Daniel')`?

Comment: Did you actually start the server, like `pg_ctl -D /path/to/database start`

Comment: @Matt I updated the code.  I am pretty sure I am connected if it returns the names of the tables inside the database. Does that sound right?

Comment: In the screenshot provided, you did not specify a database.

Comment: @n1000 I am pretty sure the syntax of the `conn = psycopg2.connect` line is correct.  I have been confused as to where the database lives on my machine.  I am brand new to postgresql and dont know where does postgresql default's to.  Do you know?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36740, just as @Scro noticed

Comment: To clarify, the top line of the QGIS connection dialog is just a friendly name.  You need to put "mb_sed_class" in the field labeled "Database".

Comment: @Scro  Thanks!!  Filling ou the database field made it work.  I knew it was something easy like that.